# how can i make u1-publish-folder (Ubuntu One) recursive into each folder

Tags: python

How do I extend this to each folder in the target folder?
you know recursive to every file in all subfolders.

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sil/+junk/utility-programs/view/head:/u1-publish-folder

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative if you really want to modify the script edit the bottom part like this:
(and yes, sorry for double posting but this keeps it cleaner)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        folder = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        print "Syntax: %s folder" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(1)
    folder = os.path.realpath(folder)
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        print "%s is not a folder. Terminating." % (folder,)
        sys.exit(1)
    # walk all directories inside `folder`
    for (dirname, subdirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
        subdir = os.path.realpath(dirname)
        if not os.path.isdir(subdir):
            continue
        reactor.callWhenRunning(process_folder, subdir)
        reactor.run()
```

This should do the same as my bash-based answer but with a simple call of *u1-publish-folder target-folder*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the script and your question correctly you could do it with a bash line like this:

```
find /path/to/target-folder -type d -exec u1-publish-folder '{}' ';'
```

Which will recursively find all folders below target-folder and call u1-publish-folder for them.
(But excluding target-folder, you'll have to call it once for that one)
If you explicitly wan't the script to do the recursion by itself please edit your question - ok?